# [tag:]s in meta profiles wrongly(?) link to meta-tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, profile-page

I've noticed that tags inside a user's profile description, i.e. `[tag:tagname]`, when viewed from the meta profile, *sometimes* link to the meta-tag, not to the main-site tag like it normally does in meta-posts or comments.

This can be seen on my stackoverflow profiles: [main-site](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4857909/lukas-rotter?tab=profile), [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4857909/lukas-rotter?tab=profile).

Strangely, on my puzzling profiles ([main-site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14478/lukas-rotter?tab=profile), [meta](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14478/lukas-rotter?tab=profile)) this doesn't occur *anymore*, all the tags link to the main site. If I remember correctly, this "fix" happened once I edited my profile again, trying out if `meta-tag` works on one of the tags. (**Edit**: This has been reset, it now links to the meta tags again, but I still have the screenshot of it linking to the main site below (2nd one))

- [Screenshot of Meta-SO-Profile linking to the meta tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um2oa.png)
- [Screenshot of Meta-Puzzling-Profile linking to main-site tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1RzR.png)

---

I've read the [official formatting help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), but it in the section `Tags` it only says

> To talk about a tag on this site, [like-this](/questions/tagged/like-this), use
>
> `See the many questions tagged [tag:elephants] to learn more.`
>
> The tag will automatically be linked to the corresponding tag info
>   page.

and in the section `Comment Formatting` it furthermore says

> - `[tag:tagname]` and `[meta-tag:tagname]` – link to the given tag's page.    Link text is the name of the tag. meta-tag only works on meta
>     sites.

which both don't seem to help me with my problem. Please also note that the `[tag:like-this]` example only links to meta *here* (I guess that's because you can't ask questions directly on the main site of this meta and therefore there also aren't any tags there) , on every other meta site I've tried it would link to the main-site.

---

Is this a bug that needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be an old bug that has been long-since fixed, but the issue is that we store both the markdown and the rendered HTML in the database, serving the rendered HTML when possible. Because of the old bug, the HTML for your profile had relative links, i.e. `/questions/tagged/java`. I've forced it to re-bake your HTML, and you now have absolute links, i.e. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java` - although actually, I suspect this should really be a protocol-relative link, i.e. `//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java`.

Comment: Thanks, it now works on my meta SO profile. Could you please also do the same on my puzzling profile? Also, I assume editing my profile, possibly adding new tags, is safe now?

Comment: @LukasRotter all I did to fix this was to make a sneaky edit to your profile text (whitespace isn't sufficient) and then undo my edit... so if you're going to edit it: that should fix it